# Keras LSTM, batch data structuring differences

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to understand the differences and implications of structuring sequential data for use in the Keras LSTM model. I would like to forecast electricity demand which has a natural daily/weekly demand shape that is driven by temperature and weekday and hour of day, for example. Say I have 1 month's worth of demands and inputs i.e. array shape (30 days * 24 hours of demand, 3 features), and I want to predict the next 30 days of demand based on expected future inputs. What are the implications of the following (particularly with respect to statefulness):

```
#A. feed in 1 batch of 1 hour at a time. this seems the slowest to train
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 3), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(n_epoch):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()


#B. feed in 720 batches of 1 hour at a time
#is this the same as A, except I need to forecast 720 hours/timesteps at a time
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(720, 1, 3), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(n_epoch):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=720, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()


#C. feed in 1 batches of 720 hour timesteps at a time
#is this the same as A, except I need to forecast 720 hours/timesteps at a time
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(1, 720, 3), stateful=True)) #probably dont need stateful=True here (?)
model.add(Dense(720))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(n_epoch):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()


#D. some variation so that number_of_batches x timesteps = 720 (no overlap of sequences). 
#Timesteps most likely in multiples of 24 timesteps representing hours of the day to capture the profile shape
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(number_of_batches, timesteps, 3), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(timesteps))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

for i in range(n_epoch):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=number_of_batches, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

I've read around so much but still don't quite get the full hang of LSTMs, so any help is much much appreciated! Any recommendations are welcome too.

Comment: Instead of calling 'model.reset_states()' at each epoch, just set 'stateful' to 'False'. 'stateful=True' simply tells the model to keep the recurrent states of the network from one epoch to the next, instead of resetting them. I think approach D fits your use case best, setting 'stateful=False' and removing 'model.rreset_states()'. You can also avoid the for cycle and set 'epochs=n_epoch', it will make the code cleaner

Comment: Thanks gionni, I left the code as is for easier comparison I suppose.  Is there a reason why you think approach D and setting stateful=False would be the best (conceptually)? I would have at least thought passing the states from batch to batch would be better as I want it to see the full history for dependencies, understanding there is a limit to how far back it can go.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'll try to expand on it tomorrow if I have time :)